# Responsive list and list items

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design

How do I make an unknown number of list items be responsive in the browser? For example, I have a one row list and would like to have 3 li elements visible at all times.  As I resize the browser window, the li elements scale so there are only 3 visible.

html:

```
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
  </ul>
```

css:

```
ul {float: left}
li {float: left; max-width: 33%}
```

I'd prefer a cross-browser method using only CSS.  If javascript is necessary, then so be it.  How do I achieve this in a responsive way for the web?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with display:table property. Write like this:

**CSS**

```
li {
    display:table-cell;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/372sV/1/

Comment: Why do you use `display: table-cell` instead of specified widths? Because 33.33% may not be split exact? Just curious when you are improving my sample code.

Comment: @Smamatti there are lot things why i use table. First every browser render '%' differently. Second if your add border & padding to on your '%' DIV it's add that in there width then broke.

Answer (score 0):

Set the size (height) for the ul and use the overflow method to hide 'additional' elements. Or use CSS to set display option of children > 3.

I think the second solution is much cleaner.

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/372sV/

```
ul {
    float: left
    width: 100%;
}
ul li+li+li+li {
    display: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```